# How to best approach adding a new template to an existing CodeIgniter project?

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to add a new template to an existing CodeIgniter 3.0 project where the original developer had not planned for additional templates/themes.

The primary objectives are to:

a) make a usable copy of all existing views and css files and leave the originals unchanged.

b) allow for core updates as they are released by the original developer that do no overwrite my changes.

My question is: To meet the previous objectives and to avoid having to manually update everywhere the developer originally referenced a view file/directory...

Should I use a CodeIgniter hook?
Should I make changes to CodeIgniter configuration files?

**Project: CodeIgniter 3.0**

*Existing directory structure:*

```
.
├── application
|   └── views
|     └── back
|       └── index.php
|     └── front
|       └── index.php
├── template
|   └── back
|     └── style.css
|   └── front
|     └── style.css
```

Proposed directory structure:

```
.
├── application
|   └── views
|     ├── back
|     ├── front
|     └── *new_template_view
|       ├── *copy_of_back
|       └── *copy_of_front
├── template
|   └── back
|   ├── front
|   └── *new_template_css
|     ├── *copy_of_back
|     └── *copy_of_front
```